# radio button list event not firing all the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a very strange issue with a radio button list where it works fine but after a few clicks it doesn't seem to fire the SelectedIndexChanged event and just remains on the same value after postback.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblShowRecords" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblShowRecords_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem >Show Active/Completed</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem >Show Active</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem >Show Completed</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Here is the event method:

```
protected void rblShowRecords_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (rblShowRecords.SelectedItem.Text)
        {
            case "Show Active/Completed":
                CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SelectAllRecords"].ToString();//"SELECT * FROM [CERecord] ORDER BY [Priority]";
                break;
            case "Show Active":
                CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SelectActiveRecords"].ToString();
                break;
            case "Show Completed":
                CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SelectCompletedRecords"].ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        CEDatabaseSource.DataBind(); //Commit the changes to the data source.
        gvRecordList.DataBind(); //Update the GridView
        rblShowRecords.SelectedItem.Value = CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand; //Update the value of the selected radio button with the selected SELECT command.
    }
```

I don't understand why it only works precisely 3 times but after, it never enters the method above.

Trying the same thing but with a dropdownlist, also works 3 times and then this error:

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation
```

Comment: When you are setting value for item in your last line of code, you are trying to set SQL query to Item value and SQL Query may contain characters that will cause invalid postback. You already know which select command to retrieve based on text so why are you trying to set select query to dropdownlist?

Comment: Well the selected.item.text is what you see in the DDL and selected.item.value is a string sql query saved in a config file. But why is it working 3 times and then it fails?

Comment: Yes but why are you setting it to Selected.item.Value? And you may have one query that contain characters like `>` or `<` that are invalid control values and will cause invalid postback

Comment: Basically I need to do this in page_load `if (IsPostBack)
        {
            CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = ddlShowRecords.SelectedValue;
            CEDatabaseSource.DataBind();
        }` otherwise when I have a certain view and click on a row to edit it, the gridview calls on the default select command and messes everything up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, remove your code that sets SQL queries to SelectedItem.Value and use SelectedItem.Text property to get command when you need it, select queries may contain characters like `>` , `<`, etc that will cause invalid postback error, you can change your code to following:

```
string GetCommand()
{
    switch (rblShowRecords.SelectedItem.Text)
    {
        case "Show Active/Completed":
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SelectAllRecords"].ToString();
        case "Show Active":
            return  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SelectActiveRecords"].ToString();
        case "Show Completed":
            return  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SelectCompletedRecords"].ToString();
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

In Page_Load

```
if (IsPostBack) 
{ 
    CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = GetCommand();
    CEDatabaseSource.DataBind(); 
}
```

Now your SelectedIndexChanged code will be

```
protected void rblShowRecords_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = GetCommand();
    CEDatabaseSource.DataBind(); //Commit the changes to the data source.
    gvRecordList.DataBind(); //Update the GridView
}
```